# Eclipse - Maven throws Error injecting: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.JarArchiver java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am using Eclipse 2021.03

When issuing maven clean install on my project (from Eclipse, right-click on parent project > Run as > Maven Clean, then same for Maven Install), Maven throws error:

"**maven-ear-plugin:2.10:ear (default-ear) @ my-services-ear ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.JarArchiver
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError**"

when executing maven-ear-plugin goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating maven-ear-plugin version from , in my case like below because I use `<properties>` section for defining versions of dependencies.  So, in your case, you might just need to update `<version>` section of `<maven-ear-plugin>` dependency.

```
<maven-ear-plugin.version>2.10</maven-ear-plugin.version>
```

to

```
<maven-ear-plugin.version>3.0.2</maven-ear-plugin.version>
```

resolved the issue for me.

Same issue and fix for IntelliJ.